# Does Github have a way to synchronize your fork with cloned repo?

Tags: git, github

Does Github offer a way to synchronize a fork of a Github repo with changes in the source repo?

For instance say I fork a repo, and rename the `master` to `upstream` which I want to keep synchronized with changes to the source repo, can Github synchronize my `upstream` with the `master` of the source repo regularly?

Comment: Do you have write access to the source repo?  (It would not be advisable to rename the upstream repository on the source repo since you may have consumers downstream.)

Comment: I don't have access to the source repo, and I don't plan to. It is mainly to keep up with updates the original owner makes to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, github does not provide it. Instead you can achieve it locally.

First, create local repository, add your own remote and retrieve it.

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
git pull origin master
```

Next step, add a remote branch to your repository that points to the original repo you forked from.

```
git remote add --track master <repo-name> git://github.com/<username>/<source-repo>.git
```

Note that master will be the branch you want to track in the forked repo. `<repo-name>` is up to you. If you want to verify, simply run `git remote` and you must see `<repo-name>` and `origin` as output.

Now, you are ready to get all new changes from original repo.

```
git fetch <repo-name>
```

A new branch called `<repo-name>/master` will be created with latest changes.

Comment: Does this approach mean that `I do not fork` the source repo directly on Github, but that the Github repo I create is initially an empty one, and I clone the source repo locally first, set a tracking reference to it, then checkout my own working branch, then push both branches to Github, so Github displays both the original remote and my own working branch?

Comment: Nop. You have to fork a repo on github and create an empty (or use another) one locally linked to github repo. Then you link your forked repo with another the one you choose (empty or not).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can synchronise it – it's called merging. You can merge your branch with master branch anytime, but if there are any conflicts (incompatibilities) – you will have to fix them manually.

For example, while in your source folder, assuming that Github is already configured:

```
git checkout upstream
git merge master
```

As I already mentioned, if you change something in your branch and master branch changes the same lines of code – automatic merge won't work, you will have to decide manually what version to keep.